# Java algorithm performance difference between Linux and Windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, performance, kernel

We observe a very significant performance difference of an algorithm in java between Linux (ubuntu) and Windows. The algorithm is running on JADE multi-agent system. In the system each agent has its own process. The agents perform computational intensive operations and communicate with each other. The difference in performance is 3x-4x in favor of Windows. Test machine is i3770 quad core (8 logical cores). We have checked with java 7 and 8, 32 bit and 64 bit version. Under Linux, all the cores have the same load: about 50% is spent in userspace and 50% in kernel. Under Windows 80% is spent in user mode, 20% in kernel.

[The PNG files contain the Java profile information sorted by various columns from Windows and Linux. (jdk8-u25-x64)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iv2nnfar4bn821t/AADnNx3shJrRkm0SFw5bRbNUa?dl=0)

Recently we doubled Linux performance using “chrt” command: “chrt -f 99 java …” which enables FIFO_SCHED scheduling for the java process.

We suspect that Linux needlessly switches between tasks too many times.

Is there a way to increase java performance on Linux to match Windows performance?

Comment: And what is this algorithm? What are the syscalls? What is the code? What JREs on each?

Comment: This question is way too generic. You can't expect to get a precise and detailed answer.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I have added link to java profiler information. I will try to extract a minimal test-case from an algorithm.

Comment: Higher kernel cpu activity on Linux could point to resource contention. C++ applications I have performance tested on Linux report high system CPU when there is thread contention - behaviour could be different in java. You could try profiling it with jvisualvm.

Comment: @eeijlar thank you for your comment. we actually used jvisualvm to profile ([see screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iv2nnfar4bn821t/AADnNx3shJrRkm0SFw5bRbNUa?dl=0)) and we didn't observe any profile difference but speed.